# getElementByTagName function needed

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to create a text area in which the user will input the auto responder code. I hope everyone knows this. The auto responder code will have a full form code provided by most of the auto responder services like mailchimp, aweber etc.

I need to use `getElementByTagName` or anything else to extract all the input elements from the pasted code.

For example I will have 3 boxes below this text area, one will have Name field, 2nd will be email field and 3rd will be a box which will add all the hidden fields extracted from the above text area.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,  [**`getElementsByTagName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/element.getelementsbytagname) exists already.